# Redirect react-router-redux push within component lifecycle

Tags: reactjs, internationalization, redux, react-router, react-redux

So I have a localised site, and need to redirect routes in certain cases. For example, if a user had their UI set to Spanish, and went to `mysite.com/about`, they would need to be redirected to `mysite.com/es/about`.

So basically, the routes are duplicated via `<Route>` components from react-router:

```js
{Object.values(UILanguages).map(locale => {
  return (
    <Route path={`${locale.basepath}`} key={locale.basepath} locale={locale} component={App} status={200}>
      ...routes go here
    </Route>
  )
})}
```

It would be simple enough to check within the `componentWillMount` lifecycle method of `<App>` to find out if I'm on the wrong `<Route>` component, but then I would have to prepend every single link in my application, which I don't want to do. Instead, I would like dynamic redirecting for foreign languages, as displayed in the first paragraph.

How is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Use the react router hooks instead it will be cleaner (smaller components) and simpler than using the component lifecycle.

https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#onenternextstate-replace-callback

in your case you need to use all 3 arguments  because the first one is the next state the second is the redirection you want to make and the third is a callback to call when you are done testing values.
i can give you an exemple about how to make this but i don't really know how your app is structured so instead check this link , it helped me a lot:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JicUNpwLzLY&t=359s

hope this helps!

ps: in some cases you need to define the `onChange` hook too example : pagination...